# AngularJs - Bindonce force refresh using refreshOn attribute

Tags: angularjs, bindonce

I am trying to force refresh my bindonce table after editing few records but I dont know how to use bindonce refreshOn attribute.

HTML Code:

```
<tbody bindonce="filteredItems" refresh-on="refreshTaskList" ng-repeat="task in filteredItems | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
<tr>
 <td><span bo-bind="task.serviceTypeName | isEmpty : 'None'"></span></td>
  <td ><span bo-bind="task.percentageCompleted | isEmpty : 'Not Started'"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I am calling this line in my Controller:

```
$scope.refreshTaskList();
```

Also, I tried calling this as well but nothing works:

```
$scope.$broadcast('refreshTaskList');
```

Can you anyone please help me how to use this in a proper manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to: `refresh-on="'refreshTaskList'"`

Example:

```
<button ng-click="refresh()">Refresh table</button>

$scope.refresh = function () {
  $scope.$broadcast('refreshTaskList');
};
```

If it still doesn't work you might have a version that doesn't contain the `refresh-on` attribute.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/nYPDMRG4b1OtkMolEEDQ?p=preview

Comment: Excellent! I never know that we have to surround refreshTaskList with single quotes.

Comment: For those looking the master branch of bindonce does not have `refresh-on` attribute baked in. You'll need to use the rebind-debug branch https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce/tree/rebind-debug which seems to have some issues still https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce/issues/42